# Python change date format for only some values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame having among some of the column location and date, and I would like to change the date format for only one location value (location = 1), from `%m/%d/%Y` to `%d/%m/%Y`.

For now I have tried several things, among which this:

```py
df.loc[(df['location']=='1'),'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[(df['location']=='1'),'date'],format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

which does not give me any error, but does not work either, meaning that it does not change the dates for the rows having location = 1.

How can I change the format in my data file just for the rows with location = 1?

Comment: Is that '1' or 1

Answer (score 0):

I got your code to work.  I modified your code by removing `()`:

```py
df.loc[df['location']==1,'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[df['location']==1,'date']
                                       ,format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

My sample data:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'location':[1,0,1],'date':['03/13/2019','14/03/2019','04/14/2019']})
```

[image: juypter notebook output]